# Inequality Regarding Random Variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X$ be a geometrically distributed random variable with parameter $\frac{1}{3}$, Y be an exponentialy distributed random variable with parameter $2$,and $Z$ be an exponentially distributed random variable with parameter $3$.

I have to find the probability that $X < Y <Z $.

To do so, I considered a fixed $X = x$. Then, $P(Z > Y > x) = \int_{x}^{\infty} f_Y(y) \cdot P(Z > y) dy = \int_x^{\infty} 2e^{-2y} e^{-3y} = \frac{2}{5} e^{-5x}.$

Summing over all $x$, I got $$P(X < Y < Z) = \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} P(X = x) \frac{2}{5} e^{-5x} = \frac{1}{3} \left(\frac{2}{3} \right)^{x-1} \frac{2}{5} e^{-5x} = \frac{2}{15e^5 - 10} \approx 9.0244 \cdot 10^{-4}.$$

However, when I ran simulations to test this, I got an answer closer to $1.38 \cdot 10^{-3}.$

Does anyone know where I went wrong/if my solution is even correct?

Comment: You need to say if $X,Y,Z$ are independent.

Comment: yes they are. I forgot to include that.

Comment: Please include all relevant details by editing your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to be specific about the parametrization of the variables in question.  For instance, the geometric distribution has two commonly used parametrizations:

$$\Pr[X = x] = p(1-p)^x, \quad x \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots \}$$
with support on the set $\{0, 1, 2, \ldots \}$, or
$$\Pr[X = x] = p(1-p)^{x-1}, \quad x \in \{1, 2, 3, \ldots \}$$
with support on $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots \}$.  Which parametrization you use will affect your answer; you have used the second and we will proceed with this.

Regarding the exponential distribution, we assume the parametrization is by rate; i.e., $$\Pr[Y \le y] = 1 - e^{-2y}, \quad y > 0$$ and $$\Pr[Z \le z] = 1 - e^{-3z}, \quad z > 0.$$

Then the subsequent calculation for the desired probability, assuming the above, is
$$\begin{align}
\Pr[X < Y < Z] &= \sum_{x=1}^\infty \Pr[Z > Y > x]\Pr[X = x] \\
&= \sum_{x=1}^\infty (1/3)(2/3)^{x-1} \int_{y=x}^\infty \Pr[Z > y]f_Y(y) \, dy \\
&= \frac{1}{3} \sum_{x=1}^\infty (2/3)^{x-1} \int_{y=x}^\infty e^{-3y} (2e^{-2y}) \, dy \\
&= \frac{2}{15} \sum_{x=1}^\infty (2/3)^{x-1} e^{-5x} \\
&= \frac{2}{15} \cdot \frac{3}{2} \sum_{x=1}^\infty \left(\frac{2}{3 e^5} \right)^x \\
&= \frac{1}{5} \frac{\frac{2}{3e^5}}{1 - \frac{2}{3e^5}} \\
&= \frac{2}{5(3e^5 - 2)} \approx 0.000902447.
\end{align}$$

This result matches yours; moreover, my simulations are consistent with this result.  Out of $10^7$ simulations, I obtained $8967$ desired outcomes, which matches the order of magnitude.  The *Mathematica* code I used is:

```
Length[Select[ParallelTable[{1 + RandomVariate[GeometricDistribution[1/3]], 
 RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[2]], RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[3]]}, 
 10^7], #[[1]] < #[[2]] < #[[3]] &]]
```

Note that the extra $1$ in the geometric distribution arises because we are using your parametrization, whereas *Mathematica* uses the first parametrization, which includes $0$.  If we remove this added $1$, then the simulation yields a much larger number of outcomes, with an empirical probability of about $0.133888$.  This corresponds to the exact value of $\frac{2e^5}{5(3e^5 - 2)}$.

Your findings might not be unreasonable if the number of simulations you used is small (hence the standard error of your probability estimate could be too large compared to the theoretical probability).  Remember, the chance of such an outcome is somewhat rare: only about $1$ in $1108$ simulations will meet the desired criteria.  In order to detect if there's an error in your implementation, you'd have to do large number of simulations.  For instance, $10^3$ simulations would give a standard error of about $9.5 \times 10^{-4}$ which is comparable in size to the actual probability, whereas $10^7$ simulations reduces this to $9.5 \times 10^{-6}$.  Another way to see this is that if you do only $1000$ simulations, your point estimate could be $0$ if no successes were observed, or it could be $0.001$ with one success.  There is very limited precision with which an estimate can be made.  Each increase by a factor of $100$ in the number of simulations will, on average, increase the precision of the point estimate by one decimal place.